# How do I force iPhone to download all message automatically?

Tags: ios, mail.app

Lately my iPhone wouldn’t download entire messages and either show “download remaining message” button or just the attached. 
This was not the behavior until some time ago. It’s new. 
I tried to delete the account and reconfigure but it didn’t help. 
What do I do?!

Comment: Can you upload the attachment you mention?

Comment: What version of ios are you using?  Are you using the apple provided mail app.  If so, look around in settings and see if there is a setting that might effect this behavior.